# Error importing csv file [Limesurvey]

Tags: csv, limesurvey

I get an error, when importing VV file. Yesterday, I exported answers and tried to import - everything was fine. Today, like an hour ago, same exported file couldn't be imported(those answers were exported ~16 hours ago).

Also, I found out how INSERT statements look, when VV file is imported successfully and when it fails. The difference is, that when import is successful every field is being imported, but when import fails, additionally it tries to insert id value of particular answer, too. What could have changed in 16hours? Could it be a Limesurvey bug?

UPDATE:

Found the problem. It depends on:

1. Which options are chosen when importing.
2. What are the response id's in survey and file. In other words, there is a match between id's in survey and id's in vv file or not.

Comment: Hi: LimeSurvey version and build number + What option selected when importing

Comment: Version 2.05+ Build 140811. Option is "Renumber the new record", Character set of the file: Automatic (UTF-8), the rest is not selected.

Comment: Tested with last version : seems OK. Try to update to last version.

Comment: Installed newest version additionally (not updated existing), then imported survey A from older version, everything is ok here, and exported A's answers.
At first I couldn't import answers, then I executed survey twice. Boom! I can import answers from survey A. Then I stopped survey B(in newer version) and started it again. Another Boom - I can't import same answers now which could be imported before stopping the survey. No matter what I do or which options are selected - I can't import any of the answers.